# How to visualize Feature branches?

Tags: process, branch, visualization

We are using separate branches for separate features and we need to visualize these branches.

Is there a tool that can help us? We do not need a tool that uses our source-repository to generate the graph. We want to use the tool for planning new branches and for visualizing them.

Comment: Which kind of VCS tool do you use? If you answer this it might be possible to answer the question better. What is the purpose to visualize them? To know which is active or not?

Comment: Hi, I do not need a tool that visualizes the existing branches in my VCS (it is Subversion). I need a tool that helps me to plan featurebranches (Which version do they have, when will they be merged back to the trunk. What are the current branches, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

- Graphviz (if you want automatic layout and may need semi-automatic generation of the visualisations),
- Inkscape (if you just want to draw a diagram)